# Can I create with DynamoDB multiple tables with secondary index concurrencly?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, create-table

I am confused by the API documentation of CreateTable from DynamoDB. I need to create multiple tables with a secondary index. From the API: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/DynamoDbClient.html#createTable-software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.CreateTableRequest-

> If you want to create multiple tables with secondary indexes on them, you must create the tables sequentially. **Only one** table with secondary indexes can be in the CREATING state at any given time.

and

> Up to 500 simultaneous table operations are allowed per account. These operations include CreateTable, UpdateTable, DeleteTable, UpdateTimeToLive, RestoreTableFromBackup, and RestoreTableToPointInTime.
>
> The only exception is when you are creating a table with one or more secondary indexes. You can have up to **250** such requests running at a time;

- Can I create now only one table with a secondary index or 250 at the same time?
- If I create multiple tables sequential without waiting on active state is this already concurrency creation?
- Must I wait on the active state for every table if I create multiple tables with secondary indexes?

Answer (score 1):

An individual *account* can only be running one "Create Index" action at a time, no matter how many tables you have.

To understand this it may help to understand what an Index is. An Index is a *complete copy* of the table, but with a different partition and sort key. So if your original table has a PK of of `userId` and a sk of `sort_key` you could now create an index where the partition key is set to `sort_key` and the sort_key is now set to `userId` creating an inverted index (a common practice in Dynamo - remember Queries in Dynamo *must* know what the PK is, so if you have UserID you could access all data of a given User, or if you wanted all Users who have a particular tag, you may have an SK item on users that is something like `TAG#ThisTag` and then you wanted all users with `ThisTag` you could do a query against the inverted index with a pk = `TAG#ThisTag` and get back a list of UserIds.)

While the CreateIndex is being run on a given table, no other actions can be run on it - it wont accept changes to the data/configuration that would cause a fault/mismatch in the copying process. This is one of the reasons a given account is limited to only one create index operation at a time.

*As a slight aside if I may - if you have a single account with multiple Dynamos all for the same product, you may want to rethink your database strategy. A single Dynamo Table can be used for many different storages if you set up your PK-SK as generic fields (ie: `pk` and `sk` as the attribute names) - No document inside your dynamo has to have the same attributes as any other. And when accessing data, each partition key is exactly as its named - a *Partition* of data that is all that is accessed when a query is made against that PK. (so if you have 100 items with PK of `USER#1` and 100 items with a PK of `USER#2` and you query against `USER#1` you only access that 100 items - the rest are ignored by the Query and never ever touched - allowing you to in effect have multiple "tables" in a single DynamoDB Table by giving them different Partition Key prefixes.)*

Comment: I does not understand what you means. On creating of a table the table is empty. This means also every secondary index is empty. And what has the creating on one table to do with a second table? There are no dependencies between the indexes of different tables. Every table is isolated. And what means the 250 in the documentation?